# Why getting Error for 1 Table when migration Database to another SQL Server Express 2014 in SQL Compare?

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm trying to move Data form one SQL Server Express 2014 to another.
First I have Imported Data though SQL Management Import/Export Wizard. THen I tried to synchronize all Tables using SQL Compare and I got following Error related to one Table:

> The following error message was returned from the SQL Server:
>
> [1105] Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run
>   storage:  422212498751488' in database 'DatabaseName' because the
>   'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded
>   files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to
>   the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the
>   filegroup. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
>   Error executing the following SQL: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] ADD
>   CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([Table1ID])
>
> The following SQL command caused the error:
>
> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY
>   CLUSTERED  ([Table1ID])

This Table is quite big with Data but not bigger than 4GB.

Reserved(KB): 3,151.496
Data(KB): 2,616.680

Free Disk Space on both Servers is > 200GB

Any idea why I'm getting this Error?

Comment: Probably your filegroup has a limit. Check it on database properties.

Comment: Where exactly I can check is there a limit?In Database Properties in Files TAB my Database has a Filegroup: PRIMARY with Initial Size (MB): 10240 and Autogrowth / Maxsize: By 1 MB, Unlimited

Comment: Try by changing this 1 MB to 50%, click [...] button to get properties dialog.